# What is the black sticky residue after heating copper hypophosphite?

Tags: redox

I am experimenting with double sided PCB (printed circuit board) via (connections from one side to the other) holes activation.

The activation is the process of making the walls of  holes electrically conductive enough to then electro plate copper. Forming a copper tube with good mechanical and electrical properties.

One activation technique consists of coating the surfaces to activate with copper hypophosphite mixed with amonia water. Then when heating at 150°C, the solution burns and leaves behind a conductive surface.

I understand the reaction produces nano particules of metallic copper. Annoyingly, this also leaves a sticky residue. Which is relatively hard to clean. But successfully cleaning it also takes most of not all of the conductive layer away. And of course it's pretty much impossible to clean within small (less than 2mm) holes anyways. Within holes this residue can leave too rough of a surface, which electroplates badly.

I know there are other techniques for via holes activation. This one has the advantage of being pretty fast with minimal steps. Which is why I am exploring it. Dip in activator making sure it gets within the holes. Cook past 150°C until black. It's now conductive. Sometimes as low as a few ohms.

The activator solution was made with calcium hypophosphite, copper sulphate, amonium hydroxide, and water. There is a bit of excess calcium hypophosphite compared to the sulfate. I filtered the calcium precipitation out. And I diluted the solution to about 15% of amonia. Finally I added 1% of non ionic surfactant (triton X).

What is the sticky residue made of? What could I try to reduce the amount of residue?

PS: I am no chemist.

Comment: Have you tried to wash your plates with some basic solution, like a sodium carbonate solution ? I guess this sticky residue may be a polymeric phosphoric acid, which should be soluble in a base, like $\ce{Na2CO3}$. If it does not dissolve this sticky residue, try with some diluted $\ce{NaOH}$ solution, cold or warm. At least, copper metal should resist to this operation.

Comment: I only used water, with and without surfactant. Copper does get attacked a tiny bit with caustic solutions. Its a good way to clean it in fact. I wonder if the nanoparticules of copper will resist. Only one way to find out. I will report here.

Comment: I tried up to a 3% solution of NaOH. For up to 10 minutes. It didn't seem to do anything to the black residue. Nothing different than just water as far as I can tell. When wet, the sticky residue can be wiped, taking with it the conductive layer. Maybe what I need, is a way to make it extremely thin. I tried diluting the activator in water. But this made for a patchy conductive layer. I will experiment with vacuuming the excess before heating.

Answer (score 2):

My leading suspect is decomposed TritonX.  [TritonX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triton_X-100) is an organic compound used as a surfactant, or synthetic "soap".

You might try to clean your substrate first with TritonX (only) solution as a *separate* step first, then rinse with distilled water.

Make your activator solution *without TritonX*, and apply it after cleaning.

After heating, there should be less undesirable residue.

Comment: That is really good information thank you. I did try with a "pure" solution. And sadly,  it wasn't noticably cleaner after heating (the amount of triton X is very minute). But it has to be better.  I also did try: ultrasonic cleaning with water and a bit of tritonX. Rinse. Dip in cationic surfactant (sold as moss killer). Not sure if I should rinse after that. And then dip in clean activator and heat. I need to do more testing. I haven't touched it in a while.

Comment: Then, I would wonder what the PCB boards were made of, and maybe try a lower drying temperature, maybe 100 - 120 C.  The other thing that comes to mind is *electrodeposition* of copper from solution.  Also, make sure your ammonia is pure and maybe go with 2-5 % rather than 15%.  Some "ammonia" sold at stores also has other ingredients.

Comment: This was a big jug of industrial 30% ammonia. I will try with a different brand and seek lab grade purity. I did try different temperatures. In fact you know there is copper when the solution turns black. Before that, its not conductive. Thank you for the recommendations. I will report here when I get back to it and do more testing. I am busy on other projects right now.

Answer (score 1):

Three months later I hope you are still interested and testing. The black residue is one (if any) of the disadvantages of this method of activation. From the literature and internet info available, there is no clear states about the need (or not) to rinse/blow/dry this residue to a minimum.

I also never trusted about the use of soap (no matter how pure), because is for sure that there are some extra ingredients added. I always believed that the use of soap is only as a surfactant and to ease the surface tension of the liquid activator, so I will be using ethoxylated nonyl phenol instead of soap (warning: like you, I am not chemist, so DO NOT trust what I am saying).

Your industrial 30% ammonia is enough and very good for this application. You do not need reactive lab grade purity for this process. TritonX seems to me very overloaded for this, so I prefer a purest surfactant like ethoxylated nonyl phenol (hope to test it in a few days or weeks).

Another not very clarified step is the oven process. When I was into PCB shop manufacturing floor, all the oven processes were carried through batch racks, so it is uncommon in this process to enter the PCBs into the oven with the activator still wet (a no-no).

You stated that you post-diluted the ammonia to 15% ¿why? ¿it was because of irritating odor? ¿another reason? Let me ask you some questions so maybe we could find some causes... (also please, clarify, at which stage, if any, did you post-diluted ammonia)

1. Of course, at first, when adding ammonia water to the solution you must be at outdoors and with some respirator mask if possible, because of the pungent odor of ammonia.
2. Then, after the complete activator solution is ready to use, and when you were hole-activating a PCB, how strong was the ammonia odor? This is a good indicator if the solution was prepared correctly. Did you was indoors? Did you make the activation process without using a respirator mask? It was odor tolerable? Did you perceive ammonia odor at this stage? If so, how much, none, low, medium, high odor, not-tolerable?
3. At the oven process, again, how pungent was the ammonia odor, if any? Did you had the oven indoors, so you can perceive the heating process odors? Take in consideration that a very precise monitoring of the oven temperature is needed since you do not want to overheat the ammonia and enter some decomposition (for health issues and for the activation process itself).

A convection oven is mandatory so you can place your PCBs vertically (NOT horizontally), and again, this is influenced if some drying is needed (or not) into the activated boards (more testing needed at this stage to observe results).

Regards.

Comment: By diluting to 15% ammonia, I meant the concentration in the final solution. For example for 1 liter of final solution, it would mean 0.5l of 30% ammonia. I did try few concentrations, ranging from 5% to almost 24%, and besides the annoying stink, I am not sure it made a significant difference.

For the smell, 15% in the final solution indeed stinks. 5% is very reasonable on the other hand. While cooking the board, the most noticable smell is of white phosphorus. But we are talking about incredibly minute amount here.

Comment: As for drying, as long as water had time to evaporate without boiling it did not seem to matter.

I found drying the PCB horizontal made for a cleaner result, simply because the activator seems to spread more evenly instead of pooling at the edges of the holes and make a thicker reside at the lowest edge of the PCB. For cooking the PCB I did it both ways unintentionally and I don't remember noticing a difference.

Comment: For the surfactant, I found positive improvement to dip into a 0.1% solution of benzalkonium chloride (found in commercial products like moss remover). Shaking the excess off, then dipping into the activator. This is a cationic surfactant and it should help break the surface tension and hold the activator on the surface to coat (thanks Applied Science on YouTube for this).

Comment: Also tried micro etching the surfaces of the hole walls with a very hot solution of permanganate + lye. It did not seem to improve anything. And it's just too dangerous and time consuming for my liking anyways. My understanding is this helps when your have those 100k RPM drill that make holes that are too smooth because it melts the epoxy a bit. Not a problem I have.

Comment: The issue with the black residue is how it often makes an uneven surface. Sometimes it clogs the holes a bit. We are talking 0.4mm to 0.8mm holes here. If one side is partially clogged, the electroplating won't be able to make it through.

Comment: After reading the original patent again, I can see that the authors clearly state that the black residue are the metallic copper particles (so, if black, then you have copper formed). Also, I can see that the common article widespreaded (from instructables) differs in many aspects from the original patent, obviously in an effort to simplify the process, but I think that in some concepts it adds complexity as well.

You can avoid desmearing (you named it microetching the holes) with permanganate if you are only making 2-layers PCBs. Only when making innerlayers is mandatory.

Comment: I recommend that you read the whole patent document carefully. My efforts now are to reduce the black residue, not in the holes, but over all the whole substrate, since it would be useful to have a batch rack of activated boards ready to enter the batch oven witthout dipping liquid solution. Also, I will be experimenting replacing ammonia with glycerol, like in the patent document examples.

Comment: One additional step may be laminating, exposing, and developing dry film over both sides, with via artwork exposing, similar to LPI soldermasking. Then you will have a board with dry film over almost all the surfaces, with the vias exposed in plain copper. Only then, you could dip the PCB into the activator (the concentrations and ingredients of the activator solution may no pose a problem for dry films, but testing is needed for Ca(H2PO2)2, but I think it is pretty safe for dry films).

Comment: With the use of previous dry film laminating, your PCB only should be receiving the activator into the holes. Of course, into the oven, you must do a pre-heating step to reach only a safe temperature before the dry film starts to melt or damage. And with hope that at this temperature, hopefully most of the water in the activator started to evaporate so maybe you could strip the dry film to continue with the heating process. More testing here is needed, since dry films tend to increase bonding to the surface after heating, but in some cases with overheating, the dry film starts to crack.

Comment: Again, these are only vague ideas. More testing and experimentation is needed, but I think that a reliable method only could be assured individually. That is, the equipment, consumables, etc. each person have available influences all of the process, and a practical solution serving all the needs for everyone (like a tutorial) it is not practical. So more testing is needed.

Comment: I have read the patent a few times. As well as a few others that talk about copper hypophosphite. If I knew what I was doing, I wouldn't be asking here. The black residue contains the nanoparticles of copper. But it is also sticky and clog holes.